# removeEventListener not removed

Tags: javascript

I must be overlooking something as my eventlistener is not removed. I created a small reproduction. I am not using anynomous functions. The signature of the addEventListener is identical to the removeEventListener. Still my listener is still being triggered when I dispatch the event.

Even though the 3rd argument is not default in any modern browser, I still added it for debugging purposes but it didn't make any difference.

Can someone please help me out here. What am I missing?

```js
function Foo(){
    this.AddComponent();
}

Foo.prototype.AddComponent = function(){
    var self = this;
    
    window.addEventListener("OnAdd",self.OnAdd,false);

    var ev = new CustomEvent('OnAdd', {
        detail: {}
    });

    window.setTimeout(function(){
      console.log('dispatched');
      window.dispatchEvent(ev)
    },1000);
}

Foo.prototype.OnAdd = function(event){
    console.log('I was fired!');

    var self = this;    
    window.removeEventListener("OnAdd",self.OnAdd,false);

    // try to fire again, which in theory should not work
    var ev = new CustomEvent('OnAdd', {
        detail: {}
    });
    
    window.dispatchEvent(ev);
}

new Foo();
```

Comment: When `OnAdd` is called as an event listener on `window`, the value of `this` is the same as the value of `window`. It isn't the instance of the Foo class that it was inside `AddComponent`. Since `this` is the same as `window`, so is `self` so `self.OnAdd` is `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `this` inside `OnAdd` is not bound to the instance.

```js
function Foo(){
    this.OnAdd = this.OnAdd.bind(this);
    this.AddComponent();
}

Foo.prototype.AddComponent = function(){
    var self = this;
    
    window.addEventListener("OnAdd",self.OnAdd,false);

    var ev = new CustomEvent('OnAdd', {
        detail: {}
    });

    window.setTimeout(function(){
      console.log('dispatched');
      window.dispatchEvent(ev)
    },1000);
}

Foo.prototype.OnAdd = function(event){
    console.log('I was fired!');

    var self = this;    
    window.removeEventListener("OnAdd",self.OnAdd,false);

    // try to fire again, which in theory should not work
    var ev = new CustomEvent('OnAdd', {
        detail: {}
    });
    
    window.dispatchEvent(ev);
}

new Foo();
```

Same code, just as an ES6 `class`:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.OnAdd = this.OnAdd.bind(this);
    this.AddComponent();
  }
  AddComponent() {
    var self = this;

    window.addEventListener("OnAdd", self.OnAdd, false);

    var ev = new CustomEvent('OnAdd', {
      detail: {}
    });

    window.setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('dispatched');
      window.dispatchEvent(ev)
    }, 1000);
  }
  OnAdd(event) {
    console.log('I was fired!');

    var self = this;
    window.removeEventListener("OnAdd", self.OnAdd, false);

    // try to fire again, which in theory should not work
    var ev = new CustomEvent('OnAdd', {
      detail: {}
    });

    window.dispatchEvent(ev);
  }

}

new Foo();
```

Comment: I was really under the impression, that explicitly scoping this in var self = this; would preserve the object reference when passed in the event listener, regardless of the event listener being executed in the window scope. 

E.g. self.OnAdd would still refer to the instantiated object. 

Really gobsmacked actually.